# Перенос f-string по PEP

Tags: python, pep8

Решил следить за написанием своего кода и столкнулся с проблемой, как правильно делать перенос строк и выражений в Python.

```
def get_message(self) -> str:
        return f'Тип тренировки: {self.training_type}; Длительность: {self.duration:.3f} ч.; Дистанция: {self.distance:.3f} км; Ср. скорость: {self.speed:.3f} км/ч; Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:.3f}.'
```

```
    def get_spent_calories(self) -> float:
        """Получить количество затраченных калорий."""
        mean_speed = self.get_mean_speed()
        return (self.coeff_calorie_1 * mean_speed - self.coeff_calorie_2) * self.weight / self.M_IN_KM * self.duration * self.H_IN_MIN
```

Как делать перенос строки (не превышало 79 символов) при этом в консоли вывод должен быть в одну строку.
Заранее извиняюсь за столь глупый вопрос)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

Почему бы не обратиться к [первоисточнику](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.

[**автоматический** перевод:](https://translate.google.ru/?sl=auto&tl=ru&text=The%20preferred%20way%20of%20wrapping%20long%20lines%20is%20by%20using%20Python%27s%20implied%20line%20continuation%20inside%20parentheses%2C%20brackets%20and%20braces.%20Long%20lines%20can%20be%20broken%20over%20multiple%20lines%20by%20wrapping%20expressions%20in%20parentheses.%20These%20should%20be%20used%20in%20preference%20to%20using%20a%20backslash%20for%20line%20continuation.%0A%0A&op=translate)

> Предпочтительный способ обертывания длинных строк - использование
> подразумеваемого продолжения строки Python внутри скобок, скобок и
> фигурных скобок. Длинные строки можно разбить на несколько строк,
> заключив выражения в круглые скобки. Их следует использовать вместо
> использования обратной косой черты для продолжения строки.

Пример:

```
def get_message(self) -> str:
    return (f'Тип тренировки: {self.training_type}; '
            f'Длительность: {self.duration:.3f} ч.; '
            f'Дистанция: {self.distance:.3f} км; '
            f'Ср. скорость: {self.speed:.3f} км/ч; '
            f'Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:.3f}.')
```

PS кроме соответствия стандартам PEP-8, код должен быть легко-читаемым. Поэтому я разбил строки таким образом.

Answer (score 2):

Вы это имели в виду?

```
def get_message(self) -> str:
return f'Тип тренировки: {self.training_type};' \
       f' Длительность: {self.duration:.3f} ч.; ' \
       f'Дистанция: {self.distance:.3f} км; ' \
       f'Ср. скорость: {self.speed:.3f} км/ч; ' \
       f'Потрачено ккал: {self.calories:.3f}.'
       
def get_spent_calories(self) -> float:
    """Получить количество затраченных калорий."""
    mean_speed = self.get_mean_speed()
    return (self.coeff_calorie_1 * mean_speed - self.coeff_calorie_2) \
           * self.weight / self.M_IN_KM * self.duration * self.H_IN_MIN
```

Comment: Да, но по новым стандартам нельзя использовать "\".